# Count number of finished tasks over total tasks in a list to display in KPI

Tags: 2010, list

My problem is this:

I need to create a dashboard/KPI in SP2010 that will show the progress of a certain project.

The progress should be counted via the number of tasks/milestones completed in the said project. Tasks can be added anytime so the progress on the dashboard should also adjust in realtime.

I noticed that a KPI/status list only counts numerical data, so question is:

Is there a way to count the number of tasks in a list (filtered by project name column) and show in the dashboard how much of the project is done based on tasks done/total tasks -- and display it as a KPI?

Thanks!

Comment: any luck with that? i'm working on the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Was working on same thing also but i found you cannot add chart/reports to dashbored unless you create a Sql Server Analyses Service (Cube) as data source, which is not feasible in our current scenario... however if you find any solution do mention it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with little effort by using XSL.
I have just posted a [blog post](http://blog.techamit.com/2014/10/sharepoint-2010-project-tasks-list.html) to answer this.

I hope it will help!